# How to use as.numeric to transform a vector of random numbers into a vector of 0,1,2?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector $(0,1,2,3,4,5)$.
I want to transform it into the following: if the value in the original vector is:

$=0 \rightarrow 0$

$> 0$ but $<5 \rightarrow 1$

$=5 \rightarrow 2$

I tried:

```
v <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
v <- as.numeric(v=0, v>0 & v<5, v=5)
```

Comment: Software-related questions are off-topic on this site. As about your code, you can start with `?as.numeric` since your code does not follow the syntax of this function at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two logical operations and add the results:

```
v2 <- (v > 0) + (v >= 5)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
v <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
v[v>0 & v<5] <- 1
v
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 5
v[v == 5] <- 2
v
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124793)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
> vs <- as.numeric(ifelse(v==0,0,ifelse(v>0 & v<5,1,2)))
> vs
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 2
```